# Does anyone know of a spell checker plugin for ckeditor that uses aspell or a similar local service instead of spellchecker.net?

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

We are using CkEditor on our CMS product and does not want to use the built in spell checker from spellchecker.net. Does anyone know of other plugins, like e.g. the old FCKeditor plugin which used aspell serverside?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A CkEditor port of the old aspell based plugin for FCKeditor is available here:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15893

Answer (score 6):

Marianna:

First of all, the reason why we want to use spellchecker.net has nothing to to with the functionality itself, both the SCAYT and the regular spell check is working great. 
However, we are using CkEditor in our CMS (CorePublish, www.coretrek.no), and using an online tool like spellchecker.net has some drawbacks:

- The free online version is at times slow, and it displays ads, both of which many of our customers will find annoying.
- Our product is sometimes installed at intranets and closed networks where internet access is not available, this means depending on an online service is a no-go.
- We had a working spellchecker included in our previous version (using FCKEditor) for free. Suddenly requiring our customers (or our self) to pay extra for spellchecking, purchasing either the hosted or licensed versions, is not something we want to do.
- We want to integrate the spell check itself with our own back end, where we e.g. store a custom dictionary for each user etc.

So based on these issues, we decided to rather go for the "old" aspell plug-in, which enables us to provide a built in, banner free spellcheck by default, and where we can control the back end our self.

regards,

Arve Skjørestad

Senior system developer

CoreTrek AS

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery Spellchecker integrates pretty well with CKEditor: http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/ckeditor.html

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. I wasn't happy with the other ones that I had found.