# How to make spell checker work for CKeditor wysiwyg editor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, spell-checking

Any edit box that I open in Firefox comes with a spell checking capability which is somehow integrated by Firefox or browsers in general.
I have a small php script which users ckeditor wysiwyg editor. How can I make spell checker active for the edit area of ckeditor?
PS.
Also an updated version of solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244510/does-anyone-know-of-a-spell-checker-plugin-for-ckeditor-that-uses-aspell-or-a-si) will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false

Answer (score 7):

`config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;`

More here: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.disableNativeSpellChecker

It switches on the browser's native spell checker. Now you probably would like to have also native context menu, in which user can e.g. pick correct version of word proposed by dictionary. By default native context menu can be opened if you press ctrl+right click. That isn't obvious and the only way to solve this issue is by removing contextmenu plugin:

`config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';`

Now you'll have native spellchecker and native context menu.

Comment: To enable the native context menu, plugins depending on the `contextmenu` plugin also have to be removed. See the various answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2246631